# VB.NET - Handle many textboxes with less code

Tags: vb.net

I got many textboxes (about 10) in a form. I want the text in the textbox to be higlighted whenever it gets foucs. The code for that looks like:

```
Private Sub txtBillNo_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBillNo.GotFocus
   HoverText(txtBillNo)
End Sub

Private Sub HoverText(ByRef ctrl as TextBox)
   ctrl.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

It works perfectly, but I though I could do some **code optimization** here. Since, I have about 10 textboxes (and many other forms containing several textboxes), I have to `HoverText(TextBox)` in every `Private Sub.. Handles TextBox.GotFocus` for every textbox in each form.

I look for any form event (or any other way) that is trigerred when focus is given to another control (textbox) within the form, either by MouseClick or TAB so that `HoverText(TextBox)` is needed to be written only once for a form.

Comment: Side note: use `.SelectAll` instead of `.Select()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all your textboxes in the `Handles` clause:

```
Private Sub atextbox_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _
 System.EventArgs) _
           Handles txt1.GotFocus, _
                   txt2.GotFocus, _
                   txt3.GotFocus, _
                   (...remaining text boxes..)
                   txt9.GotFocus, _
                   txt10.GotFocus
```

Or you can add handlers to all textboxes when loading the form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each t In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        AddHandler t.GotFocus, AddressOf HoverText
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub HoverText(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    DirectCast(sender, TextBox).SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Comment: In the first option, how do I know which textbox triggered teh event. I discovered that 'sender' is the Form.

Comment: @RajBD No, `sender` would be the textbox in a `GotFocus` handler.

Comment: Oh yeah! I was going through different error. Thought that was the case. Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The .NET way to alter the behavior of a class is to derive a new one.  That's well supported by VB.NET and Winforms as well.  For any class derived from Control, you can intercept an event by overriding the protected OnXxx event where Xxx is the event name.  You should be using the Enter event btw.  Use Project + Add Class and make the code look like this:

```
Public Class MyTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.Select(0, Me.Text.Length)
        MyBase.OnEnter(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Compile.  Go back to your form and note that you now have a new control on the top of the toolbox.  Drag it on the form and note how it now behaves the way you want it, without writing any code or event handler in your form at all.