# Select Text on click vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with vb.net in which there are quite a few textboxes in which the user enters data.
I would like to make sure that when the user clicks on the textbox the text is selected so he can enter his data.
I tried with the code but when I click on a textbox it selects all of them:

```
   Private Sub selection(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtVendita1.MouseClick, txtSchedaEm1.MouseClick ..other textbox..
        txtVendita1.SelectAll()
        txtSchedaEm1.SelectAll()
        ..
    End Sub
```

I should make as many private subs as there are textboxes, is there a way to simplify the code?

Comment: Use the Enter event so it still works when the user navigates with the keyboard.  Best way to do this is by adding a class to your project, one that derives from TextBox.  [Override OnEnter()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302594/17034), now it works for every one you add to a form.

Answer (score 2):

This why you should learn how events actually work. In an event handler, the `sender` parameter is ALWAYS a reference to the object that raised the event. That way, you can handle multiple events with a single method and always access the right object, e.g.

```vb
Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
```

The cast is required because the parameter is type `Object`, so it can refer to any type of object.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried this: Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    textBox.SelectAll()
End Sub

But textbox.selectall() doesnt work